# Flashing Mac OS 8 (1997) to bootable flash drive?

Tags: osx, usb, iso, bootable

I would like to create a bootable flash drive with an old version of Mac OS, such as Mac OS 8, just to explore it. What software can I use to flash the OS onto the flash drive?

Answer (score 0):

Just to provide a partial answer ...

I think your only hope would be [SheepShaver](http://sheepshaver.cebix.net)

I have no idea how you would actually achieve it :/